# Why do ants raid the house in summer when it is hot, but in cooler months they don't come in?

Tags: ant, home-biology

Over summer the ants invade our house, including our kitchen. In winter and the shoulder seasons they are not to be seen.

I can think of a number of possible reasons for this, including:

- they are cold-blooded, and need heat from the outside atmosphere (similar to flies), making winter too cold to go outside for ants
- ants need water, and tend to run short on it in summer when the temperature is higher, so travel further for water
- the higher temperatures cause aromas from food crumbs to effervesce more strongly, and so ants are attracted to a stronger smell
- ants natural natural nest cycle means they run their food supply low in summer and they need more

My question is: **Why do ants raid the house in summer when it is hot, but in cooler months they don't come in?**